Blank screen on netlify after a react or a vite deploy
I started learning React.js and Vite, but everytime I try to deploy a vite or react website on netlify it's always a blank screen or a "page not found"
i have tried so many things to fix it but nothing seems to work, what should I do???
My script

Could you add a bit more relevant details to this question?
Like are you trying to deploy it from a github repository? It would be helpful if you can attach some screenshots as well :)

I tried deploying it directly on netlify without using github

We need more info. Are you getting any errors from Netlify? The white screen and "page not found" screens usually indicate a failed build.

this error appears when I inspect Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


/src/main.jsx:1 load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Browsers cannot run .jsx scripts.
On Netlify, you can configure build command, and change publish directory to the output directory.

Open the browser window and right-click to select inspect. In the inspect tab, click on the console to see the error message and fix it.

It appears this error Failed to /src/main.jsx:1 load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Could you send a photo of main.jsx

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<React.StrictMode>

</React.StrictMode>,
)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
